# Is there a way to split for loop in java to do different things for values?

Tags: java, for-loop

Beginner question : is there a way to split for loop in Java ? 
for example the below,  i would like to split

```
    for(int i=0; i<bucket.size(); i++){
        do something 
    }
```

Lets say bucket.size = 10 
Split into two.

1. do something for the first 9 values in bucket
2. do something for the last value in bucket

Comment: use conditions.. `if(i < 10){/*do something*/}else ...` inside the loop

Comment: If the something is dependent on an assignment, you can use a ternary operator

Comment: Actually, there is sort of a split method, if I recall correctly, that returns a subset of the array. Just call that, passing in the proper indices.

Answer (score 3):

Most directly:

```
for(int i=0; i<bucket.size()-1; ++i){
    do something 
}
do something else
```

Using `List.sublist`

```
for (Buck buck : bucket.subList(0, bucket.size()-1)) {
    do something
}
// (Might want to check exists...)
Buck buck = bucket.get(bucket.size()-1);
do something else
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i=0; i<bucket.size()-1; i++){
    if (i < 9)
    {
    //DO
    } 
    else if (i == bucket.size()-2) 
    //-2 because the loop condition is < not <= but also includes a -1
    //Only works with bucket size 11 or greater or it will just enter the i< 9 instead
    {
    //DO for final time in loop
    } 
}
```

Just use some if else conditions inside the block to find what you need.

You can use `&&` for AND, `||` for OR, and then of course `< > <= >= ==`

Your loop will only execute 9 times though since you have it < AND -1, so the question is a little bit weird.  The final time IS the 9th time, so you only really need to the i < 9, in the case of 10.  The loop should really be:

```
    int size = 10;
    for (int i=0; i<=size-1; i++){

    }
```

If you want the loop to execute 10 times.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a `LinkedList`, you can call `removeLast` method that removes and return the last element.

```
LinkedList<Integer> bucket= new LinkedList<>();
int last = bucket.removeLast();

// do something with the last item here

for (Integer i : bucket) {
// Do something for all items except the last one            
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a while loop

```
int i = 0; 
while(i < (bucket.size() - 1))
{
    //do first nine
    i++;
}
//do last one
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want do only do something for the last value then just do it.  This presumes a non-empty list as stated by the OP.

```java
  // Doing something for first size-1 values.
  for(int i=0; i<bucket.size()-1; i++){
      //  do something with
      bucket.get(i);
  }
  // Now do something with last value.
  bucket.get(bucket.size()-1);
```

Comment: What happens if `bucket.size() == 0`? ;)

Comment: It won't be.  The OPs question implied it wasn't empty.

Comment: Which precondition? OP just gave 10 as an example.

Comment: Right!  10 was just an example but the term, `last value` implied it wasn't empty.  Which means the loop would fail and the lone statement would succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's lots of ways for you to achieve this. If your intend is just to do `something else` to the last element and `something` to the others I think you should do something like this:

```
    int lastIndex = bucket.size() - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < lastIndex; i++) {
        Type item = bucket.get(i);
        //do something with item
    }
    if(lastIndex != -1) {
        Type item = bucket.get(lastIndex);
        // do something else with item
    }
```

This way, you avoid comparing every time and save one iteration (Not a big advantage, I know).

Although, if your list is really large and you need an efficient way, or even your use case is more complicated, you should consider using `Spliterators`:

https://www.baeldung.com/java-spliterator

Answer (score 0):

you can take advantage of `skip` and `limit` methods from `Stream`

```
 //first 9 elements
 bucket.stream().limit(9).forEach(s -> {
        //do smth
 });

 //remaining elements
 bucket.stream().skip(9).forEach(s -> {
        //do smth
 });
```